# label execution in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

This is a really easy question, but if I have a bunch of instructions written for MIPS (although I assume this probably carries over to assembly in general), and there is a label at some point, does the instruction at that label get executed even if it's not explicitly called? For instance, let's say I have:

`SUB $6, $4, $3`

`BNE $6, $2, LABEL1`

`ADDI $6, $0, -8`

`LABEL1: SW $6, 0x01000`

If the `BNE` branches to LABEL1, then the ADDI gets skipped. But if BNE doesn't branch to LABEL1, then the ADDI happens, but does the next line always happen too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the *delay slot*. The branch is performed or not after the following instruction is executed. This is why it is common to see a `nop` after branch instructions in MIPS code. A branch instruction in the delay slot is usually undefined behavior.

The instruction at the destination label will only be executed if the condition is true and the branch is taken.

More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot)

Comment: BTW, that article mentions architectures with two branch delay slots. Then, in your example, the code at label would be called once or twice, but usually there is a single slot.

Comment: The real MIPS ISA (as used in CPUs like MIPS R2000 and MIPS32) has 1 branch delay slot, sufficient to fully hide R2000's branch latency.  Other ISAs can be different, but this is MIPS.  There are various academic versions of RISC pipelines that use the MIPS instruction formats, but differ from actual MIPS, often in not having any branch-delay slots.  (As well as differing in performance from R2000, e.g. multi-cycle instead of pipelined, or no bypass forwarding, but that doesn't affect the ISA unless software has to manually use NOPs to avoid hazards because of the lack of forwarding.)

Answer (score 0):

"does the next line always happen too?"

yes